# Unable to get HTML link to work, wrong target redirect

Tags: html, redirection

I'm currently trying to make a link using the `<a>` tag on my website to another one. But I always end up with a link that points to `https://<mywebsite>.000webhostapp.com/<the href>`. For a live example look at the following URL: https://b-o-p.000webhostapp.com/resend.php

Could anyone tell me why that happens?

Edit: Began to figure out what the error was. When I type in `https://google.com` in the `href` for the `<a>`, I to get to that site. When I just use `www.google.com` it takes me to `https://b-o-p.000webhostapp.com/www.google.com`.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't specify `http://` or `https://` in the `href` tag, it is a relative link, which will use the base URL of the page as root for the link.

Examples:
(Assumes your site is hosted on `http://example.com/subdir/page.htm`)

- `<a href="www.google.com">` ➜ Link to `http://example.com/subdir/www.google.com`
- `<a href="/www.google.com">` ➜ Link to `http://example.com/www.google.com`
- `<a href="https://www.google.com">` ➜ Link to `https://www.google.com`
- `<a href="http://www.google.com">` ➜ Link to `http://www.google.com`
- `<a href="//www.google.com">` ➜ Link to `http://www.google.com` (uses http because that is what the page is using, called [protocol-relative](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) URL)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you put in a links `href` attribute it can be a relative or absolute link. By just putting in `www.google.com` you're telling the browser that it should request a document named `www.google.com` from the current path of the page. By adding a simple slash to it (`/www.google.com`) you would tell it to look on the hosts root for a document named `www.google.com`. By including a complete URL you're telling to to look elsewhere and use that.